# git recursive strategy with multiple ancestors and kdiff3

Tags: git, git-merge, kdiff3

I'm running a merge with a scenario where several "common ancestors" are available so Git runs "git merge recursive" strategy.

As such, it runs a merge to create a new ancestor that will, in turn, be used as CA for the contributors I'm working on.

Ok, the problem is the following, there's a file with a conflict which "ancestor" comes from the "recursive merge" performed internally by Git, so, when I try to fix the conflict with git mergetool using KDiff3, I see the following:[image]

Is this normal? My example is a little bit "too simple" (only one line in the file, so not real), but... will having this common ancestor help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Answered by another so user here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31393044/3384609

Answer (score -2):

You should have no problem in fixing the merge conflicts. This merge strategy was defined as the default one for a reason. Try it (you might want to add a tag to be able to go back if it goes wrong).