# why merge does not cause conflict

Tags: git, version-control, merge

This question follows [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954445/git-merge-affects-on-working-directory-and-staging-area). I am trying to understand what `merge` do to avoid unwanted mistakes during it.

I have two branches:`master`,`b`. I saw an strange result of doing `git merge`. You can see output of git log *before merging*, here:

```
* 148c970 (HEAD, master) rename 1 in master to 1_master
| * ad18d9b (b) rename 1 in b to 1_b
|/  
* 15cd89b add 1 in master
```

So I had a file with name `1` in `master` and `b`. Then rename it in `master` to `1_master` and to `1_b` in `b`. Then I did `git merge`:

```
git merge b
```

I guess it causes a conflict, because merge base must be `15cd89b` and both branches introduce changes on `1`, which they don't match.

But merging did not cause any `conflict` and after merging I saw both `1_b` and `1_master` in working directory.

Note:

I think both [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35954651/1043882) and [twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14962580/1043882) in linked answers forecast  conflict in above situation.

Comment: How did you rename the file? Using git mv or just renaming it in the file system and add+deleting the file in git?

Comment: @Pod That won't make any difference. [Here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1094269/5830574) are very good explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I attempt to reproduce your issue I get a rename/rename conflict, as I would expect.  First, I created a repository and some files (with unique contents):

```
$ mkdir rename-exp
$ cd rename-exp/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/torek/tmp/rename-exp/.git/
$ cat > 1
This is file "1" in its initial state.
The file is being used
for a test of what happens with
a rename vs rename conflict
in Git.
The file needs some contents
so that git can detect the
rename when we actually
do the rename.
$ cat > 2
This is file "2".         
We give it some contents
so that it has a unique SHA-1.
$ git add .
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) a4b6f52] initial
 2 files changed, 12 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 1
 create mode 100644 2
```

Next, I create branch `b` and rename.  Note that it will not matter whether I do the rename with `git mv` or with `mv` followed by `git rm --cached` and `git add` (but `git mv` is easier, so I use it).  It is, however, important that git be able to detect the rename.  This requires that either the files match 100% exactly (the easy case) or that they match "at least 50%" (this threshold can be adjusted, but 50% is the default) when diff-ed *and* that the old name (`1`) is no longer present in both trees at the time of the `git merge`.

```
$ git checkout -b b
Switched to a new branch 'b'
$ git mv 1 1_b
$ git commit -m 'rename 1 to 1_b in branch b'
[b cc104b1] rename 1 to 1_b in branch b
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename 1 => 1_b (100%)
```

Then I do the same rename, with a different name-target, in `master`:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git mv 1 1_master
$ git commit -m 'rename 1 to 1_master in master'
[master b891757] rename 1 to 1_master in master
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename 1 => 1_master (100%)
```

Finally, I run `git merge`:

```
$ git merge b
CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "1"->"1_master" in branch "HEAD" rename "1"->"1_b" in "b"
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$
```

You'll need to show your steps (and perhaps your git version as well) in order for me to see why your merge thought each change was delete-and-create (with non-conflicting creates) rather than rename.

Other variables that affect this:

- any argument to `-X rename-threshold` during the merge (this is how you tune the 50% default);
- the value from `git config --get merge.renameLimit`
- the value from `git config --get diff.renameLimit`, if there is no setting for `merge.renameLimit`.

Comment: I guess the problem was in about file `1` which was empty. So git did not detect it is renamed when tried to compute changes. Do you think my guess is right?

Comment: Most likely, yes.  Two empty files would compare equal, but if you have additional empty files, git would not know to decide that file `1` matches `1_b` and not, say, `1_c`, etc.  Or it may just not bother with empty files since they're not very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because Git doesn't really know the concept of *renaming* a file. See the [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F).
For Git it is just `add 1_master` followed by `remove 1`. What you did is

on branch master:

- add file `1_master`
- remove file `1`

and on branch b:

- add file `1_b`
- remove file `1`

So in summary (i.e. *merge*) this gives:

- add file `1_master`
- add file `1_b`
- remove file `1`

No conflict. Both branches apply the same operation to file `1`: removing it.

Things would change, if you'd *edited* file `1` on one of your branches. Then Git wouldn't know whether to apply the *edit* or the *deletion*.