# Git merge with -X argument to override master branch's file, but still got some deleted code

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have one file in master branch like belows:

```
void func(int a, string b) {
    ...
    if (a == 1) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

....
func(1, "test");
...
```

Then I checkout a new branch b1, and do some work and change the file to :

```
void func(string c, string b) {
    ...

    ...
}

....
func("test", "test");
...
```

Meanwhile, the master branch has been updated by other guys, so i need to merge this branch (there's some reason i cannot rebase it). Since there's merge conflicts, i add the -X argument:

```
git merge -X ours master
```

It works, but with the deleted code segment:

```
void func(string c, string b) {
    ...
    if (a == 1) {
        ...
    } 
    ...
}

....
func("test", "test");
...
```

Did I miss some argument when merge?

Comment: `-X ours` does not operate on a whole-file basis. See my answer here to a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42104116/1256452

Answer (score 1):

> since there's merge conflicts, i add the -X argument

It depends *when* you added the `-X ours`: you need to properly cancel your initial merge which had conflict (git merge abort), and check the state of your code before attempting a new merge with the `-X ours` merge option.
Then you can try again.

And you need to make sure that deleted code was on the same lines as your own code (which would mean conflict, if said deleted code was modified by new versions in `master`): `-X ours` only works in case of a conflict for those lines.

Comment: Yes, i tried "git merge master" first, and got conflict. Since the current branch's code is what i need, i add the -X ours. The problem is that the deleted code is still there. The deleted code was not modified by the master branch, but there's something else modified in the same file.

Comment: @FeiyuZhou True, but you need to cancel your merge first, then try again with the -X ours.

Comment: @FeiyuZhou Then that part must not have been involved in conflict.

Comment: Yes the deleted part is not in conflict. But after i run the “git merge -X ours master” in order to solve the conflict which i does not want to solve it manually, the deleted part is not being delete as expect.

Comment: If the deleted part is not in conflict, the -X ours merge option would not change anything regarding that specific part.