# Does the source branch matter when solving Git conflicts?

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I need to make a pull request between two branches, let's say **develop** and **release**, in order to bring the new code to the release environment. I know there will be conflicts at this merge, so first I will need to address these. The current policy that the company has is not to bring **release** to **develop** so I am going to use an intermediary branch for this, let's call it **merge-branch**.

Now there are two possible approaches:

1. Create the **merge-branch** from **develop** then bring the **release** to it, solve conflicts and then get back to **release** with a pull request.

   ```
   develop -> merge-branch (creating merge-branch from develop)
   release -> merge-branch (pull from release to merge-branch in order to solve conflicts)
   merge-branch -> release (opening the pull request)
   ```
2. Create the **merge-branch** from **release** then bring the **develop** to it, solve conflicts and then get back to **release** with a pull request.

   ```
    release -> merge-branch (creating merge-branch from release)
    develop -> merge-branch (pull from develop to merge-branch in order to solve conflicts)
    merge-branch -> release (opening the pull request)
   ```

My question is:

*Are there any differences in the final result between those two approaches?*

Comment: Though both should yield the same result, if the conflict resolution is done correctly, I would still favor the first option. Makes it *slightly* more clear where changes are coming from. Difference is minor though. 
You might also try to question that company-policy. It seems all it does is hide the conflict resolution in an intermediate branch? Or is there another reason not directly merge to release?

Comment: There is no difference in *content* but there is a difference in first-parent-history. For the content part, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104116/1256452) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42099431/1256452).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do the conflict resolution correctly, there should be no difference between either approach in the final `release` branch.

There is also another option, which is to rebase `develop` on top of `release`. This would require you to solve your conflicts. Then you can easily merge `develop` into `release` without a temporary branch in the middle.

Comment: I can not rebase develop on top of release, as I have to create a pull request. But for the first part, I agree with you, I think there should be no difference.

Comment: You can still create a pull request afterwards. Once you rebase and fix-up the conflicts, nothing is stopping you from making a PR towards `release` from `develop`.

Comment: yes, but this way the code from release will go to develop, and this is something that I have to avoid. So it's one of the two approaches presented in the question. Do you have any reference for which it's safe to say that they are equivalent?

Comment: I don't have a reference, but we can follow the logic that since the intermediate `merge-branch` would have both `develop` and `release` changes, it won't make a practical difference once it's merged into `release`. The only thing that might be of consideration is who is the parent of this temporary branch. As stated in the comments, one might argue that basing yourself off of `develop` into `temp` then into `release` would convey your intentions clearer.

Comment: As a reference, I would say that the git documentation on merging and branching would give you the best "proof" that you would be fine in both cases :)